# $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] is it secure?

Tags: php, mysql, security

i have a question about these function: $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. Can somebody tell me if it's safe to use like i use it ( these form i use for new topic in forum )?

```
<form name="vpid" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);?>"  method="post">
```

Thank you

Comment: If you intend to post the form to the same address, just leave out the action attribute altogether.

Comment: I'd probably do some sanitization on it first, e.g. strip all non alphanumeric or whatever your app uses. (e.g. it's likely that a URL like `"/>` will never be valid, so why not prohibit such URLs first. Otherwise it's fine, but of course a user can just change the action using dev tools or even curl anyway.

Comment: @RichBradshaw [`>` is not valid in a URL.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/53114)

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't think of a short example - haven't had enough coffee today.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd say is that you probably don't need `REQUEST_URI` in this in this context.

If you want a form to post back to the current page, the `action` attribute can be set to blank string or a dot; you don't need to specify the whole current URL.

In cases where you do need it, the answer is that yes, `REQUEST_URI` is safe.

A lot of values in `$_SERVER` are *not* safe, so it's good to be cautious, but `REQUEST_URI` is safe because it represents the address that was used to get to the site; if the address is invalid, then the user wouldn't have been able to get to the server in the first place.

Other `$_SERVER` fields can be hacked; it's trivial to spoof things like `REMOTE_HOST` and `HTTP_REFERER`, so you should never rely on them to be reliable, but `REQUEST_URI` ought to be safe.

The main thing here though is that you shouldn't really need it anyway.

Comment: "*REQUEST_URI is safe because it represents the address that was used to get to the site*" Supposedly, just the same as supposedly the others are supposed to be what they should be. Can you say for 100% certainty that there is no way to exploit `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: I'm not so sure honestly. See a `<form action="$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']">` would mean that a requrest uri ending with `?"><script>alert(1)` would execute script. Even when I can't reproduce it because browsers escape urls usually.

Answer (score 2):

Already an old question, but no, you cannot trust `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` because, it will only be available on an apache server.

Here is how Drupal handles it on the [7.x version](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7.x)

```
function request_uri() {
  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  }
  else {
    if (isset($_SERVER['argv'])) {
      $uri = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?' . $_SERVER['argv'][0];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
      $uri = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    else {
      $uri = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    }
  }

  // Prevent multiple slashes to avoid cross site requests via the Form API.
  $uri = '/' . ltrim($uri, '/');
  return $uri;
}
```

And the WordPress version [from v3.0.0 up to now](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/load.php#L32). Its purpose is to fill in the blanks and normalize the `$_SERVER` variables.

```
function wp_fix_server_vars() {
    global $PHP_SELF;

    $default_server_values = array(
        'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => '',
        'REQUEST_URI'     => '',
    );

    $_SERVER = array_merge( $default_server_values, $_SERVER );

    // Fix for IIS when running with PHP ISAPI.
    if ( empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) || ( 'cgi-fcgi' !== PHP_SAPI && preg_match( '/^Microsoft-IIS\//', $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] ) ) ) {

        if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'] ) ) {
            // IIS Mod-Rewrite.
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'];
        } elseif ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'] ) ) {
            // IIS Isapi_Rewrite.
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
        } else {
            // Use ORIG_PATH_INFO if there is no PATH_INFO.
            if ( ! isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) && isset( $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] ) ) {
                $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
            }

            // Some IIS + PHP configurations put the script-name in the path-info (no need to append it twice).
            if ( isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) ) {
                if ( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) {
                    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
                } else {
                    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
                }
            }

            // Append the query string if it exists and isn't null.
            if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
        }
    }

    // Fix for PHP as CGI hosts that set SCRIPT_FILENAME to something ending in php.cgi for all requests.
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && ( strpos( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 'php.cgi' ) == strlen( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) - 7 ) ) {
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'];
    }

    // Fix for Dreamhost and other PHP as CGI hosts.
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'php.cgi' ) !== false ) {
        unset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] );
    }

    // Fix empty PHP_SELF.
    $PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if ( empty( $PHP_SELF ) ) {
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = preg_replace( '/(\?.*)?$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        $PHP_SELF            = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }
}
```

[Symfony HttpFoundation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1754) method is a little bit more complex.